# A few operations with df.groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I working with a forex dataset, trying to fill in my dataframe with open, high, low, close updated every tick.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# pandas settings
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 320)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 320)
pd.set_option('display.width', 320)

# creating dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/tcek3kmleklgxm5/eur_usd_lastweek.csv?dl=1', names=['timestamp', 'ask', 'bid', 'avol', 'bvol'], parse_dates=[0], header=0)
df['spread'] = df.ask - df.bid
df['symbol'] = 'EURUSD'
times = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.timestamp)

# parameters for df.groupby()
df['date'] = times.date
df['hour'] = times.hour

# 1h candles updated every tick
df['candle_number'] = '...'
df['1h_open'] = '...'
df['1h_high'] = '...'
df['1h_low'] = '...'
df['1h_close'] = '...'

# print(df)

grouped = df.groupby(['date', 'hour'])

for idx, x in enumerate(grouped):
    print(idx)
    print(x)
```

So as you can see, with for loop I'm getting groups.

Now I want to fill the following columns in my dataframe:

- *idx* be my *df['candle_number']*
- *df['1h_open']* must be equal to the very first df.bid in the group
- *df['1h_high']* = the highest number in df.bid up until current row (so for instance if there are 350 rows in the group, for 20th value
  we count the highest number from 0-20 span, on 215th value we the
  highest value from 0-215 span which can be completely different.
- *df['1h_low']* = lowest value up until the current iteration (same approach as for the above)

I hope it's not too confusing =)
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's convinient to reindex on date and hour:

`df_new = df.set_index(['date', 'hour'])`

Then apply groupby functions aggregating by index:

```
df_new['candle_number'] = df_new.groupby(level=[0,1]).ngroup()
df_new['1h_open'] = df_new.groupby(level=[0,1])['bid'].first()
df_new['1h_high'] = df_new.groupby(level=[0,1])['bid'].cummax()
df_new['1h_low']  = df_new.groupby(level=[0,1])['bid'].cummin()
```

you can `reset_index()` back to a flat dataframe.

Comment: level=[0,1] means grouping by index, in our case 2-level index, 0 is Date, 1 is Hour. and using [0,1] considers groups of a particular date and all its hours.